# Share Scala class in test folder with Java tests in Maven

Tags: java, scala, maven, unit-testing

I have a Maven project with mixed Java and Scala code. I want to use an auxiliary class located in the scala test folder for Java tests. The file tree is like below, omitting packages:

```
+ test/
  + java/...
    - SomeTest.java
  + scala/...
    - Aux.scala
    - OtherTest.scala
```

I want to import code from `Aux.scala` for use in the `SomeTest.java` class. It works fine in my IDE, where all folders are marked as test folders. However when building this project in Maven I get an import error from the Java compiler.

How can I configure Maven to use the Scala test code for Java tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to resolve dependencies on Scala classes in the Java test-compile phase, you have to bind the `testCompile` goal of the `scala-maven-plugin` to the `process-test-resources` phase. That way, the Scala classes are already compiled when you compile the Java test classes.

The following snippet should do the trick:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.4</version>
  <executions>
    <!-- Run scala compiler in the process-test-resources phase, so that dependencies on
         scala classes can be resolved later in the (Java) test-compile phase -->
    <execution>
      <id>scala-test-compile</id>
      <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The complete build element of my `pom.xml` for a mixed Java/Scala project looks the following:

```
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
  <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>

  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.4</version>
      <executions>
        <!-- Run scala compiler in the process-test-resources phase, so that dependencies on
             scala classes can be resolved later in the (Java) test-compile phase -->
        <execution>
          <id>scala-test-compile</id>
          <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>testCompile</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.18.1</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
        <stdout>W</stdout> <!-- Skip coloring output -->
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>scala-test</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <suffixes>(?&lt;!(IT|Integration))(Test|Suite|Case)</suffixes>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>integration-test</id>
          <phase>integration-test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <suffixes>(IT|Integration)(Test|Suite|Case)</suffixes>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Seems to work, and a concise solutions. Sadly most of these Maven configs are still Voodoo to me.